# Добавление текста в input из select

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Есть у меня такой код.

```
<select class="select">
  <option value="1">Один</option>
  <option value="2">Два</option>
  <option value="3">Три</option>
  <option value="4">Четыре</option>
  <option value="5">Пять</option>
  <option value="6">Шесть</option>
</select>
```

И есть **input**, в котором может быть текст, но его лучше не трогать, но при этом добавить значение **value** из **select**..

Как это реализовать при помощи JS?
Начал с этого:

```
$('input').val($('input').val() + $('.select option:selected').val());
```

На этом и закончил..

Выручайте.

Comment: `$('.select').val()`

Comment: @Igor, а разве не так как я написал? Мне же нужно достать значение из выбранного пункта, а потом добавить к существующему тексту инпута.

Comment: код - в ответе.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$(function(){
  let input = $('#test'),
      inpVal = input.val();
  
  $('.select').on('change', function(){
    input.val(inpVal + $(this).val());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="select">
  <option value="1">Один</option>
  <option value="2">Два</option>
  <option value="3">Три</option>
  <option value="4">Четыре</option>
  <option value="5">Пять</option>
  <option value="6">Шесть</option>
</select><br />
<input type='text' id='test' value='Текст' />
```

Comment: То что нужно, спасибо!

Answer (score 3):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".select").change(function(){
    $('.input').val($('.input').val() + $('.select').val());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="select">
  <option value="1">Один</option>
  <option value="2">Два</option>
  <option value="3">Три</option>
  <option value="4">Четыре</option>
  <option value="5">Пять</option>
  <option value="6">Шесть</option>
</select>

<br/>

<input class="input" value="aaa"/>
```

Comment: Во, то что надо.. Только как сделать чтобы было в инпуте только одно число? Т.е. либо 1, либо 2, а не 1234 и т.п.

Comment: @CbIPoK2513, тогда это надо в вопросе указать. Мы же не телепаты знать это заранее.

Comment: @Other, да, я понимаю.. Просто не учёл, извините.

Answer (score 0):

Помогло решение от [@Igor](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/577752/217579). Немного модернизировал и заработало.
Если нужно делать полную замену содержимого, то

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".select").change(function(){
    $('.input').val($('.select').val());
  });
});
```